# Using Poisson family for log+1 counts in GLM

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model, poisson-distribution, spatial

I'm running a GLM using counts as my response variable and would normally use `family=poisson`. But I'm also running SAR models, which couldn't easily handle my counts as there was such a small amount of variation between them (high number of counts at very low numbers) so my supervisor suggested I use the hack of `log(counts)+1` as my new response variable. Should I be using the family Poisson?

The use of the family Poisson will give more conservative results (significance wise) when compared to the same model without Poisson family specified, but will obviously give me warnings as I have non integers. Because of this (I assume) it won't give me an AIC either.

Comment: Once you move to log(counts + 1) you move away from Poisson modelling. The two aren't compatible: you lose the theory and you don't input transformed variables into Poisson regression any way.  You don't explain SAR. In total there is not much detail here to guide advice.

Comment: The fact I mentioned I'm using SAR models was basically to explain why I am using the transformed counts as my response (to keep things constant throughout my analysis). By the sounds of it I shouldn't be using Poisson as my transformation violates the assumptions of the Poisson family.

Comment: Thanks for the detail, but you still haven't explained SAR. Please see http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1707/is-it-reasonable-to-put-try-to-avoid-acronyms-in-the-help-on-asking-questions?cb=1 for evidence that many TLAs are not universally understood. I don't know about violating assumptions; the point is that using such a transformation is not the way to handle Poisson data.

Comment: Ah I see, sorry! By SAR I'm meaning simultaneous autoregressive models, they're models that can take into account spatial auto-correlation by using a weighted neighbor matrix. Tutorials I've seen on their use allow for a GLM to be created and then fed into the simultaneous autoregressive format to account for the fact that locations close to each other are likely to be similar, whereas distant locations are more likely to be very different from each other.

Comment: It should be possible to write a spatial version of integer-valued AR (including Poisson AR) models.